# Shell script to list the first or last n lines of a file

Tags: shell-script

I want to write a script that lists either the first n lines or the last n lines of a specified file.

```
cd
        $1=filename
        $2=string
        $3=lenght

if [ "$filename" == "head" ]

#If the user uses the head command then do the following.

then [ "$filename" == "tail" ]
        head -n 10 /MyDirectoryGoesHere
else
#If the user uses the tail command do this instead.

        tail -n 10 /MyDirectoryGoesHere
fi
```

When I run this command I keep getting an error "Unexpected token near else" and I was told to add a for loop but don't know how or where. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I posted an answer about `bash` syntax for if constructs and case switches, but the real answer to this command is: just use the `tail` and `head` commands directly.  They can already accept multiple files as arguments.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ might help you find some problems too

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

(1) An if-then-else-fi construct should look more like this:

```
if [ "$myvar" = "value" ]; then
  # do stuff
elif [ "$myvar" = "othervalue" ]; then
  # do other stuff
else
  # do still other stuff
fi
```

(2) You could just use a case switch:

```
case "$myvar" in
  "value")
    # do stuff
    ;;
  "othervalue")
    # do other stuff
    ;;
  *)
    # do still other stuff
    ;;
esac
```

(3) I don't know what you're trying to do with the `$1=filename` commands, but it's definitely not the right way to do it, whatever it is.  ;)

Check out [the wooledge bash tutorial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) for more.